# ANR due to createBitmap

Tags: android

I am getting ANR in my app and anr traces points to createBitmap in below code:

```
if (loWidth > 0 && loHeight > 0) {
    obWidth = loWidth;
    obHeight = loHeight;
    obBitmapBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(obWidth, obHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    obCanvasBuffer = new Canvas(obBitmapBuffer);
        }
```

Any thoughts????

Comment: An ANR comes from spending 5-10 seconds tying up the main application thread. The statements in your question will not take 5-10 seconds to execute. Please explain, in detail, what "anr traces points to createBitmap" means.

Comment: This is the anr trace: "main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4168aca8 self=0x415c5400
  | sysTid=7249 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1074225492
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=101811 stm=11088 core=0
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:809)
  at com.MyAnimationView.prepareBuffers(MyAnimationView.java:472)
  at com.MyAnimationView.onMeasure(MyAnimationView.java:220)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16505)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)

Comment: That happens to be where you were at the point in time of the ANR. The ANR is coming from a lot more code than that. Use Android Studio's method tracing to see where you are spending your time. That being said, creating a `Bitmap` in `onMeasure()` of your custom `View` is not going to work well, if you are doing that on every `onMeasure()` call.

Comment: I have still not fixed the issue but your(@CommonsWare) advice is helpful to move forward.